# SCSS - add transition to after element

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions

I want to add transition to after element on hover, problem is that is not working. I want to hover on image and add background-color over it and apply transition on .5s . Content is for testing only.

```
.imageGallery1 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;

  &:hover {
    &::after {
      content: '>';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: $main-color;
      opacity: 0.3;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add relevant html and maybe the output CSS in a working code snippet

Comment: I don't know if that's possible, Try testing in with JQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this and it works!

```
& a {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1090;
    &::after {
      content: '>';
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: $main-color;
      opacity: 0;
      transition: 0.5s opacity;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    &:hover::after {
      opacity: 0.3;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work just fine at https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MZNjeZ assuming the container of `.imageGallery1` has dimensions (*`width`, `height`*) so that it can expand to `100%` of it.

Comment: @Freestyle09 oh sorry, missed that. Which properties do want to transition? Also keep in mind that transition requires two states before and after. So the element that transitions must exist before starting the transition

Comment: I want to transit all properties which I defined in after element